# Kubernetes: cpu request and total resources doubts

Tags: kubernetes

For better understand my doubts, I will put an example

Example:

We have one worker node with 3 allocatable cpus and kubernetes has scheduled three pods on it:

- pod_1 with 500m cpu request
- pod_2 with 700m cpu request
- pod_3 with 300m cpu request

In this worker node I can't schedule other pods.

But if I check the real usage:

- pod_1 cpu usage is 300m
- pod_2: cpu usage is 600m

My question is:

Can pod_3 have a real usage of 500m or the request of other pods will limit the cpu usage?

Thanks

Pietro

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what the real usage is - the "request" means how much resources are guaranteed to be available for the pod. Your workload might be using only a fraction of the requested resources - but what will really count is the "request" itself.

Example - Let's say you have a node with 1CPU core.

**Pod A** - 100m Request

**Pod B** - 200m Request

**Pod C** - 700m Request

Now, no pod can be allocated in the node  - because the whole 1 CPU resource is already requested by 3 pods. It doesn't really matter which fraction of the allocated resources each pod is using at any given time.

---

Another point worth noting is the "Limit". A requested resource usage could be surpassed by a workload - but it cannot surpass the "Limit". This is a very important mechanism to be understood.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes will schedule the pods based on the `request` that you configure for the container(s) of pod (via the specs for the respective `Deployment` or other `kind`s).

Here's an example:

For simplicity, let's assume only one container for the pod.

```
  containers:
  - name: "foobar"
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "300m"
        memory: "256Mi"
      limits:
        cpu: "500m"
        memory: "512Mi"
```

If you ask for `300` millicpus as your *request*, Kubernetes will place the pod on a node that has *at least* `300` millicpus allocatable to that pod. If a node has less allocatable CPU available, the pod will not be placed on that node. Similarly, you can also set the value for `memory` request as well.

The `limit` works to *limit* the resource use by the container. In the example above, Kubernetes will evict the pod if the container ends up *using* more than 512MiB of memory; once evicted, the pod will be placed on a node that has at least `300` millicpus available (and if no such node exists, the pod will remain in `Pending` state with `FailedScheduling` as the reason, until a node with sufficient capacity is available).

Do note, that the resource `request` works only at the time of pod *scheduling*, and not at *runtime* (meaning, the *actual consumption* of the resources will not trigger a re-scheduling of the pod even if the container used more resources than what it requested as long as it remains below the `limit`, if specified).

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#how-pods-with-resource-requests-are-scheduled

So, in summary,

- The total of all your `request`s is used as the what can be allocated regardless of the actual runtime utilization of your pod (as long as the limit is not crossed)
- You can `request` for 300 millicpus, but only use 100 millicpus, or 400 millicpus; Kubernetes will still show the "allocated" value as 300
- If your container crosses the limit, it will get evicted by Kubernetes